# Total Black Ink Coverage for a .25" Dot pattern on a hexagon pattern.

Tags: geometry

In effort to clarify my question to you.. I've drawn it out on Illustrator for you all. Thanks again for your help and I really appreciate it.

I'm looking for two radius sizes...

My diagram will show you what I'm looking for.

I downloaded a program that helps me calculate the total ink coverage on any print surface... Hence the 52.54%... Unfortunately it doesn't tell me the proper size I need  for the dots. That's where you guys come in. Thanks again.

[image]

Comment: i don't understand the question. it asks "How big would the hexagon need to be"? is that the spacing between each black dot? .25" is not an area. is it a radius?

Comment: yes sorry.. I'm new at this . I need to know how big the hexagon would need to be , based on its radius when you have a .25" dot on all 6 corners and in the center.

Comment: no you haven't answered my question

Comment: Yes the spacing between each black dot. .25" is the size of each dot

Comment: .25" radius or diameter?

Comment: .25" diameter sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you focus on a single hexagon on your grid, you have a whole dot in the center and six partial dots at the corners.  What is the total area of black inside the hexagon, expressed in full dots?  What is the area of a dot in square inches?  For $60\%$ coverage, you divide the total area of the dots by $0.60$ to get the area of the hexagon.  Given the area of the hexagon, you need to compute the radius.

Comment: Thanks for your hint Ross, are you able to make this into an algebraic equation for me...

Comment: Yes I am able to, but please show some effort.  Where are you stuck.